# how to remove button from time slider of google earth plugin

Tags: button, time, google-earth-plugin

I use "ge.getTime().getControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_SHOW); " to display the time slider of google earth plugin.
In GEP 6 version, the time slider contains sevral buttons, "a zoom out button", "a zoom in button", and another button which can travese a time range in a much faster speed(it has a kind of "play", "pause" function, when you mouseOver it, it says "click to toggle time slider animation"). I want to remove this button from the slider. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API method (as of Earth v6.1 with API v1.009) to modify the look and/or features of the time slider UI.  You could theoretically create your own custom UI and use it instead of the default one, however.

Comment: Could you provide me the reference/link for creating custom UI? Or is that possible to disable the button of time slider?

Comment: To be clear:  You cannot modify the UI to disable that button.  If you want to create a custom UI you can make it look like whatever you want, and then assign API calls to clicks on your interface.  For example a click somewhere on some button you create for "play" might call ge.getTime().setRate(3600) or whatever ... see http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/time.html for more details on what you can do